# How to add metadata in Event entity of Eventflow

Tags: .net, cqrs, event-sourcing, event-flow

I am working on a web solution that uses .NET 6 framework as backend with EventFlow (Event-sourcing & CQRS).
All of my events are store in the table EventEntity :

[image: EventEntity table]

I would like to add additional information in the *Metadata* attribute. I read [the documentation](https://eventflow.readthedocs.io/Metadata.html) but I don't understand about how to do it :

The documentation :

[image: Documentation]

The *Metadata* attribute is in JSON format :

[image: Metadata in json]

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the anwser.

By the use of `IMetadataProvider`

Example :

```cs
public static readonly string UserNameKey = "username";
public static readonly string UserAccountKey = "useraccount";

public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ProvideMetadata<TAggregate, TIdentity>(TIdentity id, IAggregateEvent aggregateEvent, IMetadata metadata)
   where TAggregate : IAggregateRoot<TIdentity>
   where TIdentity : IIdentity
{
   var userAccount = this.identityService.GetUserIdentity();
   var userName = this.identityService.GetUserName();
   yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(UserNameKey, userName);
   yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(UserAccountKey, userAccount);
}
```